# TFS - Rebinding solution to new TFS when prior TFS no longer available

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, source-control-bindings

The prior instance of TFS I was using is no longer available and I have a test project I want to bind to the new instance of TFS.  However, when I try to add the solution to source control, the error message tells me that the collection is not available on the server.  I have deleted all old source control files, and it still has the old bindings somewhere.

Does anyone know how to remove ALL bindings so I can just simply start over again with a new instance of TFS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike .... Don't have the answer, but I do have some questions.  So you have gone into Team Explorer and added the name of the new TFS Server? And this new server has a collection name of the same name that the solution was in on the old server, and this collection name is what is in Team Explorer?

Comment: Mike --- you may find this helpful.  http://zayko.net/post/How-to-permanently-remove-TFS-Source-Control-association-bindings.aspx It purports to show you how to manually remove SCC bindings.  Not the best solution, but if it works??

Comment: This is the right answser, but there is a very BIG but.  If your TFS server is not available and you do anything else to your project you are hosed!

Answer (score 2):

Goto File->Source Control->Change Source Control,  unbind/disconnect all projects and solution.

Comment: This does not work.  I do highlight each project, but eh Disconnect button never is active.  Only the unbind button is active.